# Can Artifactory keep builds based on build time rather than the version number?

Tags: build, repository, artifactory

My team performs multiple builds a day with same version number.

Is there a way for Artifactory to retain builds based on the time it was built instead of different version number?

If not, is there any repository manager that can suffice this need?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please add some more info for your needs. What do you mean by retain builds? Keep artifacts? Keep build info? What CI server do you use? Is the version is the version of the build or the source?

Comment: @gba Due to the nature of application we are working on, we cannot increment version number per build. (i.e. 2.1.3.4 > 2.1.3.5 and so forth) so there are time when we make changes/fix bugs and have to build using the same version number 2.1.3.4. I was wondering if the repo can keep builds based on the time it was built rather than over-writing the previous build with the same version number.